# How do I get LLVM types from Clang?

Tags: c++, llvm, clang

I'm looking to write a tool using Clang. The details are fairly immaterial, but what I'm looking to do is get an llvm type from Clang. For example, I'd like to go from "printf" to `llvm::Function*`, and "size_t" to a `llvm::Type*`. But I can't find any functions in Clang that give out these functions. I've decided that I can ask Clang to mangle the names, and then ask the `llvm::Module*` for the data- but I can't find how to get an `llvm::Module*` that corresponds to a Clang invocation.

How can I get the internal LLVM data from Clang?

Comment: Take a look at `C++ LLVM API` option on http://llvm.org/demo . If that's what you want, then you can achieve same effect by calling `clang` with `march=cpp` or something like that.

Comment: Look around `lib/CodeGen/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, the code generation APIs are not part of Clang's public API. This is for good reason, because they are awful.

However, you can create a `clang::CodeGen::CodeGenModule`, which you can use to codegen a given TU into a provided `llvm::Module`. Then, you can get the mangled name of a symbol by using the `getMangledName` function on the `CodeGenModule`.

However, do not attempt to use the provided functions for converting from a `clang::QualType` to an `llvm::Type*`- they are unusably broken. The only viable strategy I have found for reliably performing this conversion is to find a function with a signature, for example, a member function, and then query the Module for the type of that parameter, for example, `this`. But this is pretty ABI-specific and a nasty hack. You can also compute the LLVM type name that Clang generates for a given type and search for it in the module, but this is not always successful.

Comment: I'm a beginner of clang. I have a naive question, what the role of the "CodeGen" module in clange. What does it do? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In general, you cannot. clang internals are made in layers as well. So, you cannot simply grab a piece of AST and say 'Hey, give me a function'. AST is converted to LLVM IR at the IR generation step module at a time. This way we can be sure everything is parsed and semantically correct and complete.

So, if you really need all this sort of thing, then you need to hook into clang really late, after IR generation and try to operate on loosely coupled AST and LLVM IR at that time.

Comment: That's fine by me, but I've been poking around Clang's reference pages and they are *terrible*. If you could post a few more details about exactly how to achieve this, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry to steal your thunder, but I felt compelled to post a more complete answer.